# How do I run python file in new commandline window in gvim

Tags: python, vim

It used to open new command line window before, but now it is not happening in gvim. I want to run my python file and get output in somewhat like this window

[image: The commandline output I meant]

But the appearance is following:

[image: The real output]

edit - I have a doubt that why didn't `!python %` work for me? It worked before and showed output in new commandline window like before. Here is my vimrc
[My vimrc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYNLm.png)

Comment: 1) `!python %` produces the same result?
2) Have you installed any additional settings for vim?

Comment: I don't have Windows system to test, perhaps you can try `:! cmd 'python....'`? I don't know if the syntax is correct, but this may open a new windows command window.

Comment: I got it from the below answer. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Could you please answer the edit. It is my request @Kent

Answer (score 0):

Under Windows make use of `:h :!start` like this:

```
:!start python %
```

Comment: Will never forget you. You have helped me a lot